# Grouping ModelForm fields by Model Field Attributes

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I've got two models, `Question` and `Project`. `Project` has a `ManyToManyField` referencing `Question`:

```
## models.py

class Question(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(
        max_length=4000,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    question = models.CharField(
        max_length=4000,
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )

class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        blank=False,
    )
    questions = models.ManyToManyField(
        Question,
        blank=True,
    )
```

From these I have a `CreateView` and a custom form assigning the `CheckboxSelectMultiple` widget to the `ManyToManyField`.

```
## views.py

class ProjectCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Project
    form_class = ProjectForm


## forms.py

class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['name','questions',]
        widgets = {'questions':forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()}
```

So, what I want to do now is group the individual labels and checkboxes for the questions `CheckboxSelectMultiple` form field according to each question's category. Something along the lines of this (not sure exactly how it would work):

```
{% for field in form.questions %}
    {% regroup field by <INSERT MYSTERY CODE> as question_list %}
    {% for category, field in question_list %}
        {{ category }}
        {{ field }}
    {% endfor%}
{% endfor %}
```

**EDIT:**

A more detailed example of one approach I've tried:

```
{% for field in form.questions %}
    {% regroup field by field.category as question_list %}
    {% for category, fields in question_list %}
        {{ category }}
        {% for f in fields%}
        {{ f }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor%}
{% endfor %}
```

The above results in `TypeError: 'BoundWidget' object is not iterable`

Comment: Is the code (that you posted at the end of your question) working? How is the output different from what you expect?

Comment: Have you read the [`regroup` docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) ? The examples there look very similar to this case

Comment: I have read the docs. The example there refers to grouping objects from a model based on their attributes, rather than grouping form fields derived from a model based on the attributes from the source model. That's my issue, how to access the model attributes of the object from which the ManyToManyField choice was derived.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to figure this out for the best part of a week. I was looking for a simple solution but no luck. The following seems to achieve what you want.

```
## forms.py

from itertools import groupby
from django import forms
from django.forms.models import ModelChoiceIterator, ModelMultipleChoiceField

from .models import Project, Question


class GroupedModelMultipleChoiceField(ModelMultipleChoiceField):

    def __init__(self, group_by_field, group_label=None, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        ``group_by_field`` is the name of a field on the model
        ``group_label`` is a function to return a label for each choice group

        """
        super(GroupedModelMultipleChoiceField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.group_by_field = group_by_field
        if group_label is None:
            self.group_label = lambda group: group
        else:
            self.group_label = group_label

    def _get_choices(self):
        if hasattr(self, '_choices'):
            return self._choices
        return GroupedModelChoiceIterator(self)
    choices = property(_get_choices, ModelMultipleChoiceField._set_choices)


class GroupedModelChoiceIterator(ModelChoiceIterator):

    def __iter__(self):
        """Now yields grouped choices."""            
        if self.field.empty_label is not None:
            yield ("", self.field.empty_label)
        for group, choices in groupby(
                self.queryset.all(),
                lambda row: getattr(row, self.field.group_by_field)):
            if group is None:
                for ch in choices:
                    yield self.choice(ch)
            else:
                yield (
                    self.field.group_label(group),
                    [self.choice(ch) for ch in choices])


class GroupedCheckboxSelectMultiple(forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple):

    def optgroups(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        """
        The group name is passed as an argument to the ``create_option`` method (below).

        """
        groups = []
        has_selected = False

        for index, (option_value, option_label) in enumerate(self.choices):
            if option_value is None:
                option_value = ''

            subgroup = []
            if isinstance(option_label, (list, tuple)):
                group_name = option_value
                subindex = 0
                choices = option_label
            else:
                group_name = None
                subindex = None
                choices = [(option_value, option_label)]
            groups.append((group_name, subgroup, index))

            for subvalue, sublabel in choices:
                selected = (
                    str(subvalue) in value and
                    (not has_selected or self.allow_multiple_selected)
                )
                has_selected |= selected
                subgroup.append(self.create_option(
                    name, subvalue, sublabel, selected, index,
                    subindex=subindex, attrs=attrs, group=group_name,
                ))
                if subindex is not None:
                    subindex += 1
        return groups

    def create_option(self, name, value, label, selected, index, subindex=None, attrs=None, group=None):
        """
        Added a ``group`` argument which is included in the returned dictionary.

        """
        index = str(index) if subindex is None else "%s_%s" % (index, subindex)
        if attrs is None:
            attrs = {}
        option_attrs = self.build_attrs(self.attrs, attrs) if self.option_inherits_attrs else {}
        if selected:
            option_attrs.update(self.checked_attribute)
        if 'id' in option_attrs:
            option_attrs['id'] = self.id_for_label(option_attrs['id'], index)
        return {
            'name': name,
            'value': value,
            'label': label,
            'selected': selected,
            'index': index,
            'attrs': option_attrs,
            'type': self.input_type,
            'template_name': self.option_template_name,
            'wrap_label': True,
            'group': group,
        }


class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['name', 'questions']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProjectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['questions'] = GroupedModelMultipleChoiceField(
            group_by_field='category',
            queryset=Question.objects.all(),
            widget=GroupedCheckboxSelectMultiple())
```

Then the following should work in your template:

```
{% regroup form.questions by data.group as question_list %}
{% for group in question_list %}
<h6>{{ group.grouper|default:"Other Questions" }}</h6>
<ul>
  {% for choice in group.list %}
  <li>{{ choice }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Make sure you add a `__str__()` method to your `Question` class so that the question names appear correctly.

You need `GroupedModelMultipleChoiceField` and `GroupedModelChoiceIterator` to ensure your choices are properly grouped within the field instance. This means you are able to use `{{ form.questions }}` in the template to render a structured list.

However, if you want to use the `regroup` tag in a template, each choice needs to have the group name as an attribute. The `GroupedCheckboxSelectMultiple` widget provides this.

Credit to the following page for part of the solution:

https://mounirmesselmeni.github.io/2013/11/25/django-grouped-select-field-for-modelchoicefield-or-modelmultiplechoicefield/